# Using nodejs archiver to download multiple google cloud storage files and zip them

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download files from google cloud storage and zip them.

```
async function makeZippedFiles(destination, all_file_links) {

console.log("In the zip file function");


for (let i in all_file_links) {
    let name = all_file_links[i]['name']
    let archive = archiver('zip', {
        zlib: {level: 9} // Sets the compression level.
    });


    archive.on('error', function (err) {
        throw err;
    });

    let output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + `/${name}.zip`);


    console.log("loop number", i);

    let sourceFile = all_file_links[i]['source'];

    console.log(sourceFile, name);

    let remoteFile = bucket.file(sourceFile);

    let read_file = remoteFile.createReadStream();

    await archive.append(read_file, {name: name});

    read_file
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .on('response', function (response) {
            console.log("writing file", name);
            //  console.log(response);
            // Server connected and responded with the specified status and headers.
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log("file downloaded", name);
            // The file is fully downloaded.
        })


    archive.pipe(output);

    archive.finalize();
}


}
```

In the example on top, I am looping through all files and creating individual archives. i.e., if I download two files, I would be creating two separate archives. This works.

However, if I want to zip all the files into one archive, I get the following error:

> start of central directory not found;   zipfile corrupt.   (please
>   check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
>   appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)

The code I used is:

```
async function makeZippedFiles(destination, all_file_links) {
    console.log("In the zip file function");
    let archive = archiver('zip', {
        zlib: {level: 9} // Sets the compression level.
    });

archive.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});

let output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + `/${destination}.zip`);


for (let i in all_file_links) {
    let name = all_file_links[i]['name']

    console.log("loop number", i);

    let sourceFile = all_file_links[i]['source'];

    console.log(sourceFile, name);

    let remoteFile = bucket.file(sourceFile);

    let read_file = remoteFile.createReadStream();

    await archive.append(read_file, {name: name});

    read_file
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .on('response', function (response) {
            console.log("writing file", name);
            //  console.log(response);
            // Server connected and responded with the specified status and headers.
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log("file downloaded", name);
            // The file is fully downloaded.
        })


    archive.pipe(output);

}

archive.finalize();



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It was carelessness actually.

```
async function makeZippedFiles(destination, all_file_links) {
    console.log("In the zip file function");
    let archive = archiver('zip', {
        zlib: {level: 9} // Sets the compression level.
    });

archive.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});

let output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + `/${destination}.zip`);

archive.pipe(output);


for (let i in all_file_links) {
    let name = all_file_links[i]['name']

    console.log("loop number", i);

    let sourceFile = all_file_links[i]['source'];

    console.log(sourceFile, name);

    let remoteFile = bucket.file(sourceFile);

    let read_file = remoteFile.createReadStream();

    await archive.append(read_file, {name: name});

    read_file
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .on('response', function (response) {
            console.log("writing file", name);
            //  console.log(response);
            // Server connected and responded with the specified status and headers.
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log("file downloaded", name);
            // The file is fully downloaded.
        })



}

archive.finalize();

}
```

I moved the archive.pipe(output) before the for loop and it works.

Comment: what is all-file-links how to get it?

Comment: That is something I pull from the database and I loop through the files given there.